# Keeping a list of array elements in certain state

Tags: arrays, indexing, lookup

I have a long array of elements. This is an embedded platform, and each cycle I need to do an operation on all elements which have some flag set.

Only a few of the elements have the flag set at any one time. Because of performance reasons, I can not run trough the whole array.

I realize that one solution might be to build a list of the array indices of the elements having the flag set, and run through this list instead of the whole array. This list would then be updated each time a flag is set/reset.

I'm guessing this is a old and "solved" problem but I'm missing the vocabulary to describe it properly. What are the best practices for this problem, and what is it called?

Thank you

Comment: When a flag is set? You could create a queue of pointers which points to the element with the flag set. When a flag is set, a pointer is added to the queue. An other task could get the queue and do whatever you want with the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word you are looking for is a set. You are right about keeping the flagged ones in some sort of subgroup (what you call list), but a list is ordered. You don't need this ordering capability to store a bunch of flagged elements; you want a set, which is a subset of all your elements in your array.

Not having them ordered gives you performance advantages, specially on deletion, because you don't have to move all the elements of the list that are after the one you remove. Also on random position access, you have constant time if you use a HashSet. On a somewhat "bad" side, iterating through a set object is usually a bit less intuitive than a list, making you use an Iterator object.

Comment: Thanks, knowing the name for this gave me the lead I was looking for. I'm on a platform where pointers and dynamic memory allocation are disallowed, so I need to implement the subset using another array. Any disadvantages or gotchas about using an array for this? One disadvantage I guess is that I dont know exactly how many elements are flagged, so I dont know how big the subset array needs to be? I was thinking maybe the subset array could be a ring buffer? Thanks

Comment: Using a simple array for this will have disadvantages. You'll lose time in reinventing typical collection methods that you'll need to manage this new array, for example a "contains" method to check if one of your elements is flagged. But the worse is you'll lose a lot of performance (if you don't want to code a hash function and a somehow complex data structure), because without dictionary capabilities, for example to look for one element, you'll have to iterate through all of the flagged elements instead of accessing it in constant time.

Comment: Also you'll need to keep a counter of how many flagged elements you have at a given time, and you'll have to alloc for as many elements as your starting array has if you don't have dynamic allocation. Using a buffer is meaningless, buffers are useful if you can discard old data when the buffer fills, but you can't discard flagged elements. What you could do is mantaining your subarray ordered by something, reordering everytime you insert/remove an element (this is expensive performance wise). That way you'd have log(n) time to check if an element is in your subarray or not using binary search.